# winui3 Treeview control: How to show tooltip on hover of items in treeview

Tags: treeview, tooltip, uwp-xaml, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

Can someone please help me to know how I can add tooltip for Treeview control on hover?

[Treeview control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWiS2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bind it or set directly to `ToolTipService.ToolTip`.

```xml
<TreeView
    Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TreeViewItem
                Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind Tip, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```